# ComposeBar frame update issue using Autolayout update?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, chat

I am working for chat application and using PHFComposeBar for message input. I implemented compose bar through the auto layout. But compose bar not updating automatically and not updating table bottom when text editing and open editing mode, which is above composed bar.

I have to implement bottom display message position same in every case for updating text or open compose bar.

Thanx In Advance...

Comment: what are the constraints you have set to the bar?